# Makefile: common error "No rule to make" but only on Linux6, working on Linux4

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I'm getting error that "No rule to make target 'xxxx.o', needed by 'yyyy.a'
This is a very common error but I'm getting this only on Linux6, same makefile is working on Linux4. Files for which I'm getting this error are "cade_table.c" and "cade_text.c". Following is the snippet of my makefile

```
GENC=   cf_grammar.c cf_lex.c
GENH=   cf_grammar.h
GEN=    ${GENC} ${GENH}
LEXSRC= cf_grammar.y cf_lex.l
HDR=    cade.h cns.h das.h dvs.h em.h mminit.h udlparse.h udl.h scm.h stm.h \
    cf_das.h uf.h cade_screens.h sb.h tba.h
SRC=    cade.c cns.c das.c dvs.c em.c mminit.c udlparse.c udl.c scm.c stm.c \
    cf_add_das.c cf_add_dvs.c cf_readcf.c das_args.c cade_udf_init.c \
    uf.c cade_table.c errord.c getaport.c fmtlist.c dviewer.c \
    cade_screens.c cade_screens_init.c app_actions.c sg.c\
    sb.c tba.c so_kb_act.c so_kb.c mp.c scrollable.c \
    lib_x_combobox.c lib_xi_util.c lib_xi_resnames.c combobox.c \
    cade_txt.c version.c pushButtonArray.c getport.c
```

Both the files for which i get this error are already present in that path. When i modify my make file and move these two files at the end, all other files compile except these two. Following is the snippet of "ls"

```
[nk@serv cade]$ ls -l cade_t* 
-rw-r--r--. 1 nk cws  65066 Oct  7 12:56 cade_table.c
-rw-r--r--. 1 nk cws    189 Oct  7 12:53 cade_table.h
-rw-r--r--. 1 nk cws 102055 Oct  7 12:56 cade_txt.c
[nk@serv cade]$
```

After getting this error if i make my project from central level code gets compiled. but its not compiling when out script tries to compile it.
Any idea what is wrong?

Regards,
Nitin

Comment: What error are you actually getting exactly? What `make` command are you running? Is that the entire makefile?

Comment: Use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) and run it as `remake -x`

Comment: You have no explicit make rule for the object files in question, and the suffix rule that might otherwise clean up that situation has been disabled (probably via a .SUFFIXES: rule).  I don't have enough information to guess why the build works under other circumstances.